# Plotlabel too high issue (V12.3)

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, labeling, version-12.3

I think I started to notice this issue with plots when I updated to version 12.3 a couple weeks ago but didn't pay too much attention. Now it's really bugging me because I have a presentation of this data coming up. (Please note I changed the code a bit for privacy but it still shows the behaviour.)

[image]

Looking at other `PlotLabel` posts on SE and the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabel.html), I'm a bit confused as to why the plot label isn't sitting neatly above the plot as expected. I tried a couple of tweaks with `ImagePadding` etc. and tried removing all the graphics options except `PlotLabel` to no avail. I don't really want to use `Labelled` either since it should be working more predictably in my opinion.

Any ideas? Is there an explanation for this? Is anyone else seeing this behaviour in 12.3 with `PlotLabel`?

```
MakeTimeSeriesGraphic[ds_] := 
 Module[{tally, g, prod, dates},
  prod = ds[1] // Values // First;
  dates = FromDateString[#, DateFormat -> "ISODate"] & /@ (ds[All, "date"] // Normal);
  tally =  Tally[dates];
  g = TimeSeries[tally, {dateStart, dateEnd}, MissingDataMethod -> {"Constant", 0 }];
  DateListPlot[
   g,
   PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   PlotLabel -> Style[prod, "Subitem"],
   PlotStyle -> SelectColor,
   PlotRange -> All,
   ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 1}}
   ]
  ]

Block[{var},
 var = Table[MakeTimeSeriesGraphic[data[i]], {i, Length@data}];
 GraphicsGrid[
  Partition[var, 4],
  ImageSize -> 960,
  Spacings -> Scaled[0.01],
  Frame -> All
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: I get an error `GraphicsGrid::list: {} is not a list of lists.` when running your code on 12.3

Comment: `dates` code was missing. Should work now with some synthetic data in into `Tally`.

Comment: still does not work. same error. What happens if open a new notebook, with clean kernel, and paste the same code you posted there into a cell, and run your code copied from the above?  There is no `data`.  MWE should be self contained  to be to run it.

Comment: I've seen this type of issue before when working on my version of `GraphicsGrid`. Essentially, the issue is that `PlotLabel` is placed outside of the `ImagePadding`, but is included in `ImagePadding` when measuring it. This means that `GraphicsGrid` leaves enough space for `PlotLabel` with the `ImagePadding` setting, but it then gets placed outside anyway. Until they fix it, I you can use either the top `FrameLabel` instead of `PlotLabel`, or you can try [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/) (which can add the grid however)

Comment: (there's a typo in the last part of the above comment: `PlotGrid` *cannot* add the gridlines)

Comment: @LukasLang Hence it is a bug in `PlotLabel`? Have you reported it to the support?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to user Lukas Lang's helpful comment, `FrameLabel` does appear to be a predictable workaround for this issue. Using the below code returns the correct placement.

```
FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, Style[prod, "Subitem"]}}
```

[image]